# Is resize2fs the only tool to shrink ext4/3/2 filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, software-rec

I'd like to adjust the partition layout on my SSD a bit.

It looks as all the tools (`gparted`, etc) rely on `resize2fs` from `e2fsprogs`.

And `resize2fs` fails me with a (clearly wrong) message about minimum filesystem size. I think it's related to 4k block size of the SSD.

Besides, this `resize2fs(8)` paragraph reads strikingly unprofessional to me:

[image: resize2fs manpage screenshot]

---

Are there other ext4 implementations? How can I shrink my filesystem when `resize2fs` fails?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the exact error message given by `resize2fs`?

Comment: @StephenKitt not quite, unfortunately. It's on another machine which isn't close physically; but if memory serves me, the message is similar to what [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=506740) shows, except perhaps for different device (`/dev/sda2`, not `img`) and different numbers.